# google maps api java

Tags: java, google-maps

i have a console application, needs to find the distance and route between two places using the google maps api. that means i do not have a browser and hence no javascript. is it possible to do it using java using a HTTP request or something. i have tried geocoding and can find the latitude and longitude of a given address using HTTP requests. how to find distance and routes using java.

Comment: I don't think this is available via the service, only their javascript API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google only provides this in javascript.
However, there is a [request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=235) to provide it in java also. So possibly, it will be there in the near future.

The fact that there is no out-of-the-box solution from google, doesn't mean that you can not create one for yourselve of course...

[EDIT]
For example, you could read the sourcecode of [your directions in html](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=from+37.771008,+-122.41175+to+37.62345,+-122.41175&output=html) to find the distance and the route.

Comment: Be aware that obtaining the directions by any means other than the authorised Javascript call and for the purposes of displaying it in conjunction with a Google Map is a violation if the Terms.

Answer (score 2):

[Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) provides a javascript engine for Java applications. You can play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use official [Java Client](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/client-library) for Google Maps

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

Take a look at `com.google.maps.DistanceMatrixApi` and `com.google.maps.DirectionsAPI`

Code sample for Distance Matrix API ([Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix)):

```
    public static List<DistanceMatrixRow> distance() {
    List<DistanceMatrixRow> results = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        GeoApiContext ctx = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(API_KEY).build();
        String[] origins = {"New Yourk, NY"};
        String[] destinations = {"Jersey City, NJ"};
        DistanceMatrix response = DistanceMatrixApi.getDistanceMatrix(ctx, origins, destinations)
            .units(Unit.METRIC)
            .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
            .await();

        results.addAll(Arrays.asList(response.rows));
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        logger.error("ApiException: ", e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("InterruptedException: ", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("IOException: ", e);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Code sample for Directions API ([Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions))

```
public static List<DirectionsRoute> routes() {
    List<DirectionsRoute> results = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        GeoApiContext ctx = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(API_KEY).build();
        String origin = "New Yourk, NY";
        String destination = "Jersey City, NJ";
        DirectionsResult response = DirectionsApi.getDirections(ctx, origin, destination)
            .units(Unit.METRIC)
            .mode(TravelMode.TRANSIT)
            .transitMode(TransitMode.BUS)
            .await();

        Arrays.stream(response.geocodedWaypoints).forEach(System.out::println);
        results.addAll(Arrays.asList(response.routes));
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        logger.error("ApiException: ", e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("InterruptedException: ", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("IOException: ", e);
    }

    return results;
}
```

I invested my own time to investigate how to use Google Maps SDK. At the time I was looking at this there was no any docs on how to use that Java Client. If you found my answer helpful, please consider leaving a vote.